# Validation multiple OS support

Tags: java, deployment, continuous-integration, verification, continuous-deployment

I develop java agent that is about to be deployed on all possible Application Servers on different Operation Systems with multiple java versions.
I want to validate that my application will work properly on all possible permutations of the above.
One way i see, is to create set of virtual machines, each will have one of possible permutations. I don't like this way, because it requires multiple VMs. I am currently checking usage of dockers. Are there any other options?

Thanks, Yuri

Comment: How is creating multiple dockers so different from creating multiple VMs?  What differences are you expecting to see in your Java application on different OSes?

Comment: I can create dockers on my PC, integrate it as part of CI/CD and other developers can use it on their local PCs. Each docker image can have its own combination of OS\AS\Java. This approach still heavy, but at least more convenient than using several VMs.

Comment: You can also create VMs on your PC, deploy them to a server and allow others to run them too.  Perhaps they are easier to script up/instrument. I assume you need to have these VMs running for continuous integration, so you really need a server for these.

Comment: I want to allow simultaneous running for several developers. In case it is on my\remote server it will allow only single user run.

Comment: You have a server which can only run one VM at a time?  Could you not have a bigger server, or smaller VMs?

Comment: I could have it, but still, lets assume i have 9 permutations of OS\AS\Java (which is much more) and lets assume i have 3 developers, it makes me to have 27 VMs. Looks too much. I am looking for better approach.

Comment: If you have a one continuous integration system and this one system runs all tests on an agent running on all 9 VMs, it shouldn't matter how many developers you have. The 9 VMs doesn't even have to be all on the same machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100342/discussion-between-yurir-and-peter-lawrey).